# MS Access VBA: Calculate Median without iterating through records

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to find a quicker way to calculate my medians in Access. You can see the code below where it queries one item code at a time, sorts, and then calculates the median. Sometimes there are 600 item codes and those items can each have a 1000+ bases associated with it. The particular table I am working with has 150,000 total records for example and it is going really slow. Is there a better way to calculate each records median all at once as opposed to one item code at a time.

```
Function FIncPercentile(ByVal posCode As Single, ByVal k As Single, ByVal tbl As String) As Variant

Dim rstRec As Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Single
Dim res, d1, d2 As Currency

' Create recordset from query
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rstRec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Co, Base " & _
                              "FROM " & tbl & " " & _
                              "WHERE Code = " & pos & " " & _
                              "ORDER BY Base ASC;")

' Skip if there are no matches
If IsNull(rstRec!base) Or rstRec.RecordCount = 0 Then
    FBasePercentile = Null
    Exit Function
End If

' Count records
rstRec.MoveLast
n = rstRec.RecordCount
rstRec.MoveFirst

' Calculate the index where k is the percentile
i = n * k

' Test the decimal and find value accordingly
If i = Int(i) Then
    rstRec.Move i - 1
    d1 = rstRec!base
    rstRec.MoveNext
    d2 = rstRec!base
    FIncPercentile = (d1 + d2) / 2
Else
    i = Round(i + 0.5, 0)
    rstRec.Move i - 1
    FIncPercentile = rstRec!base
End If

End Function
```

Comment: have you tried opening a recordset for each table ordered by co, base  and iterating through each co in an outer loop calculating the median with filters in an inner loop?

Comment: You could probably adapt the DMedian function and example from Microsoft's site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789431%28v=office.12%29.aspx  - or is that where you got your code?

Comment: How many unique tables - if there's just one - I would think you'd see an immediate increase by creating a parameter query on the table where code is the parameter. Use the parameter querydef to create the recordset - instead of dynamic SQL  - AND make sure you have an index on both code and Base.

Comment: Is that a typo in your function declare `ByVal posCode As Single` - then you use `"WHERE Code = " & pos` .. Which is correct - AND is it actually a SINGLE - not integer or long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Median function in Access. Excel has one but I believe it's limited to 30 numbers, so even if you wanted to try using an Automation function, I don't believe it would work for your case.

I think you may see a noticeable speed increase by fine tuning your function and by letting Microsoft's Jet Engine pre-compile your query.

- Make sure you have the Base and Code fields indexed in your table(s)
- Create a Parameter Query with Code having the criteria parameter
  [What Code]
- Optimize your function with Recordset WITH construct, declared
  variables and matched field types (Code = Long Integer???)

Time it before and after all these changes and see if there's any noticeable difference

I corrected a couple typos that may not be typos - and I make an assumption that CODE is a long integer - which again I may be wrong. Also my changes are prefaced by '***************

> **CREATE Precompiled Parameter Query**

Create New Query called "**qdfPrepMedian**"

Copy/Paste SQL >> `PARAMETERS [What Code] Long; SELECT Co, Base FROM <YourTableName> WHERE Code = [What Code] ORDER BY Base ASC;`

Save the query

> **Adjusted Function**

```vb
Option Explicit

'***********************
' changed posCode to Long
'***********************
Function FIncPercentile(ByVal posCode As Long, ByVal k As Single, ByVal tbl As String) As Variant

    '***********************
    ' CREATE/USE Precompiled Parameter Query
    ' Create New Query called "qdfPrepMedian"
    ' Copy/Paste SQL >> PARAMETERS [What Code] Long; SELECT Co, Base FROM <YourTableName> WHERE Code = [What Code] ORDER BY Base ASC;

    Const QRY_BY_CODES  As String = "qdfPrepMedian"

    Dim qdf     As QueryDef
    '
    '***********************

    Dim rstRec  As Recordset
    Dim db      As Database
    Dim n       As Integer
    Dim i       As Single

    ' Declare all Currency variables on separate lines
    ' Otherwise they will be variants
    Dim res     As Currency
    Dim d1      As Currency
    Dim d2      As Currency

    Set db = CurrentDb

    '***********************
    ' Create readonly recordset from querydef
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs(QRY_BY_CODES)
    qdf.Parameters("What Code") = posCode ' matches LONG variable passed to function
    Set rstRec = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly) ' Readonly is sometimes faster
    '***********************

    ' Use WITH rstRec
    With rstRec

        ' Skip if there are no matches
        If IsNull(!base) Or .RecordCount = 0 Then
        '*** Is this a type ***
        '    FBasePercentile = Null
        ' Should it BE
            FIncPercentile = Null
            Exit Function
        End If

        ' Count records
        .MoveLast
        n = .RecordCount
        .MoveFirst

        ' Calculate the index where k is the percentile
        i = n * k

        ' Test the decimal and find value accordingly
        If i = Int(i) Then
            .Move i - 1
            d1 = !base
            .MoveNext
            d2 = !base
            FIncPercentile = (d1 + d2) / 2
        Else
            i = Round(i + 0.5, 0)
            .Move i - 1
            FIncPercentile = !base
        End If

    End With

End Function
```

Comment: @Andre thanks for improving my post. I can't figure out the changes. I thought I saw some kind of VB tag but it's not visible in post. What do I need to do next time?

Comment: In the Revision history, switch to `side-by-side markdown` to see the change. I inserted `<!-- language: vb -->`, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting . This is needed when a more popular language tag is present (usually `sql`). I have this line in my "SO template file", because I need it so often. :)

Comment: Cool. That will help a lot. I was starting to add extra ' at end of lines to get rid of the annoying unending highlights of comment lines

Comment: ( cc: @Andre ) I find that `lang-vbs` looks a bit nicer for VBA code, while `lang-vb` is the better choice for VB.NET.

Comment: @GordThompson: thanks! But are you sure there is actually a difference? All I could find was https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/lang-vb.js which seems to be used for `lang-vb` and `lang-vbs`, and my guess would be that is also used for both tags `vb.net` and `vba`.

Comment: @Andre - I'm quite sure that there *used to* be a difference, but perhaps not any more.